# Zeroclipboard is report as a accessibility issue

Tags: javascript, accessibility, zeroclipboard

When I run accessibility test, if I have an instance of ZeroCLipBoard I got an error.

For example with axe:

```
Ensures <object> elements have alternate text
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After instantiating your zeroClipboard you can do:

```
    const zcContainerId = ZeroClipboard.config('containerId');
    $(`#${zcContainerId}`).attr('aria-hidden', true);
```

Removing the element from the accessibility tree.